# Populating Java Object List to index zero on each update

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sorting, indexing

So here I've created an Object List as follow

```
private List<Post> postList;
```

Suppose I populated this list with 10 objects of Post class.

Can someone please explain to me how can I insert a new 11th in this case Object to index 0 of the list and increase all subsequent index by 1.

i.e Insert 11th object to the first position that is to index 0 and the object that was initially at index 0 should move to index 1 and so on for subsequent objects.

Comment: `postList.add(0, new Post());`

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the revert. But have one more question. Won't it replace the first object of index 0 instead of pushing it to index 1?

Comment: Nope. It does not. As clearly stated in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `postList.add(0,new Post(<arguments>));` this will

> - Insert the specified element at the specified position in this list.
> - Shift the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>     subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)